# How can I make a turtle start from the endpoint of another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

For instance: I made a square using a turtle, and another turtle should start from the endpoint of the square turtle, not from the beginning.

```
hexagonTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
def hexagon(hexagonTurtle, size):
hexagonTurtle.pendown()
hexagonTurtle.pencolor('yellow')
hexagonTurtle.pensize(10)
hexagonTurtle.left(90)
for i in range(6):
    hexagonTurtle.forward(size)
    hexagonTurtle.right(60)
hexagonTurtle.left(60)
hexagonTurtle.back(size)
hexagonTurtle.left(60)
hexagonTurtle.back(size)
hexagonTurtle.right(210)

pentagonTurtle = turtle.Turtle()

def pentagon (pentagonTurtle, size):
pentagonTurtle.penup()
pentagonTurtle.forward(430)
pentagonTurtle.pendown()
pentagonTurtle.pencolor('green')
pentagonTurtle.pensize(10)
pentagonTurtle.left(90)
for i in range(5):
    pentagonTurtle.forward(size)
    pentagonTurtle.right(72)

hexagon(hexagonTurtle, 120)
pentagon(pentagonTurtle, 120)
```

Comment: Note indenting on SO is used to mark lines as code. If all lines aren't given the same amount of additional indenting (4 spaces, or 1 tab), it breaks Python's block-indentation. Read the help in the editor for more information, then please fix the sample code indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then create a second turtle from scratch and adjust it to match your first turtle, another approach you can use, given the design of your program, is to simply *clone* your first turtle:

```
hexagonTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
hexagon(hexagonTurtle, 120)
pentagonTurtle = hexagonTurtle.clone()
pentagon(pentagonTurtle, 120)
```

It will start out with the same position and orientation as the turtle of which it is a clone.  The complete example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def hexagon(turtle, size):
    turtle.pencolor('yellow')
    turtle.pensize(10)

    turtle.left(90)

    for _ in range(6):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(60)

    turtle.left(60)
    turtle.backward(size)
    turtle.left(60)
    turtle.backward(size)
    turtle.right(210)

def pentagon(turtle, size):
    turtle.pencolor('green')
    turtle.pensize(10)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(430)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.left(90)

    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(72)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 500)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-100, -200, 900, 300)  # for demonstration purposes only

hexagonTurtle = Turtle()
hexagon(hexagonTurtle, 120)
pentagonTurtle = hexagonTurtle.clone()
pentagon(pentagonTurtle, 120)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`turtle.position()`/`turtle.pos()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.position) to get the position of a turtle, and [`turtle.goto()`/`turtle.setpos`/`turtle.setposition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.goto) to set the position of a turtle. Similarly, use [`turtle.heading()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.heading) to get where a turtle is facing and [`turtle.setheading()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading) to set where a turtle is facing.

```
pentagonTurtle.penup()
pentagonTurtle.goto(hexagonTurtle.pos())
pentagonTurtle.setheading(hexagonTurtle.heading())
```

Comment: You can simply do `goto(turtle.pos())`, you don't need to unpack the return value.

Comment: @cdlane: but what if I *want* to unpack it?